# Preference is not working while a method called from child class

Tags: magento2, module, plugin, magento2.3.5, preference

I created a preference for the method `_applyOptionsPrice()` in `Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Price.php` class.
The preference is working while the `_applyOptionsPrice()` was called from the same class but the Price.php class was inherited by two class.
They are :

1. `Magento/Bundle/Model/Product/Price.php`
2. `Magento/ConfigurableProduct/Model/Product/Type/Configurable/Price.php`

While the `_applyOptionsPrice()` was called from the above two classes my preference method didn't worked.

I declared the preference in di.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">    
        <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Price" type="Vendor\Module\Preference\Price" />
</config>
```

and this is my preference class:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Preference;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductTierPriceExtensionFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductTierPriceInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\CatalogRule\Model\ResourceModel\RuleFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Api\GroupManagementInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Price extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Price
{
    

    public function __construct(
        RuleFactory $ruleFactory,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
        Session $customerSession,
        ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
        GroupManagementInterface $groupManagement,
        ProductTierPriceInterfaceFactory $tierPriceFactory,
        ScopeConfigInterface $config,
        ProductTierPriceExtensionFactory $tierPriceExtensionFactory = null
    )
    {
        parent::__construct(
            $ruleFactory,
            $storeManager,
            $localeDate,
            $customerSession,
            $eventManager,
            $priceCurrency,
            $groupManagement,
            $tierPriceFactory,
            $config,
            $tierPriceExtensionFactory
        );
        
    }

    protected function _applyOptionsPrice($product, $qty, $finalPrice)
    {
        // Here is my custom code
    }
    
}
```

"[I found a same issue in plugin from this link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11699)"

Please give me a suggestion to solve this error!!

Comment: Did you mean a Plugin or a Preference? Can you put the code that you use to declare your Preference/Plugin and the class where you override this method?

Comment: @cnbandicoot I mean Preference. Please find the updated question